# Is it safe to iterate through a stack frame?

Tags: c, stack-unwinding, libunwind

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437045/how-do-you-programmatically-obtain-a-stack-trace-of-a-child-process-from-its-par), I was trying to see if I could programmatically obtain a stack trace of a child process from its parent.

I've successfully done so, but now another question has arisen in my mind - is it safe to directly examine these frames during program execution? I'm defining "safe" here as meaning "will not modify the values on the child's stack".

For example, here's a sample stack trace I obtained from running the NPB-Serial CG Class A benchmark:

```
0x400c7e : (conj_grad_+0x12e) [0x400c7e]
  Saved regs:
    RIP: 0x400c7e
    RSP: 0x7ffe5e3662a0
    RBP: 0x36b1
0x401ec8 : (MAIN__+0x739) [0x401ec8]
  Saved regs:
    RIP: 0x401ec8
    RSP: 0x7ffe5e366300
    RBP: (nil)
0x402b39 : (main+0x1d) [0x402b39]
  Saved regs:
    RIP: 0x402b39
    RSP: 0x7ffe5e368d40
    RBP: (nil)
0x7f76b7114ec5 : (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f76b7114ec5]
  Saved regs:
    RIP: 0x7f76b7114ec5
    RSP: 0x7ffe5e368d50
    RBP: (nil)
0x400a89 : (_start+0x29) [0x400a89]
  Saved regs:
    RIP: 0x400a89
    RSP: 0x7ffe5e368e10
    RBP: (nil)
```

I would like to obtain a dump of the stack by copying the values at each stack-pointer entry - for example, by starting at `0x7ffe5e368e10` and copying every value from that address to the current stack pointer into a separate location.

Are there any risks to doing this?  Or am I thinking about this incorrectly (as in, there's an easier way to do this)?

Comment: If the other process is still running then yes there's a risk. What if the other process does a function call while you're copying or worse, does a few `returns`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg While this is happening, the child process is stopped via `ptrace`, so I don't think that would be a concern, would it?

Comment: In that case, since there's no chance of the call-stack changing, then it should be "safe", or at least you should be able to get the whole call-stack but once you let the process start executing again it  will start to get inaccurate pretty quickly.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I've got no plans to let it start executing again in my final program (in fact I'll likely send it a `SIGKILL` myself after I get the trace), so that answers my question.  Thank you!  If you'd like to put your comment in an answer, I'll mark it as my accepted answer.

Comment: You're outside of the language. Define "safe".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Safe" as in "not going to modify values on the child process's stack".

Comment: Add this crucial detail into your question please.